Why is this ending up in an infinite loop
I am working on leet code 69. Sqrt(x).
Why is this ending up in an infinite loop.
def mySqrt(x):
    """
    :type x: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    l, r = 0,x
    result = 0
    while l <= r:
        m = l + ((r-1)//2)
        if m**2 > x:
            r = m - 1 
        elif m**2 < x:
            l = m + 1 
            result = m
        else:
            return m
    return result

print(mySqrt(5))
I would expect r value to reduce until the pointer cross but that does not happen.

Why does m = l + ((r-1)//2) say 1 there?

You should not be subtracting 1 from r in the calculation of the midpoint. Instead, simply use (l + r) // 2 (or l + r >> 1). The calculation can also be simplified to remove the result variable and just return the right bound.
l, r = 0, x
while l <= r:
    m = (l + r) // 2
    if m * m > x: r = m - 1
    else: l = m + 1
return r

